# RSA decoding with public key or veryfing

Tags: c#, rsa

I have the following problem:

My application receives a certificate with the public key, an RSA encoded (with private key) sha256 signature  and a bunch of data.

I must check if the sha256 hash of the data is the same as the RSA encoded hash.
It looks like:

```
bool checkSHA(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] RsaSHASign, byte[] dataToCheck)
{
    byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey();


    RSACryptoServiceProvider crsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    //Get an instance of RSAParameters from ExportParameters function.
    RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = crsa.ExportParameters(true);

    //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values.
    RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = publicKey;
    //Import key parameters into RSA.
    crsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);   

    SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create();
    byte[] hashValue1 = sha.ComputeHash(dataToCheck);

    string OID = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256");

    //here I must check if the counted hash is the same as the one passed as RSA encoded
    return crsa.VerifyData(RsaSHASign, OID, hashValue1);
}
```

What I would really need is the hash value **before** Rsa encoding but I guess it's not possible without the private key.

Unfortunately VerifyData always returns false even that I know that the hashes are the same (before RSA). I'm really stuck :(

I hope the the solution isn't difficult but somehow cannot figure it out.
I tried to use BouncyCastle and openssl wrapper but with no success either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this way:

```
X509Certificate2 Pe = new X509Certificate2(Pe_file);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa_e = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Pe.PublicKey.Key;
if (rsa_e.VerifyHash(hash, "SHA256", data))
{
    Debug.Print("OK");
}
```

`hash` is SHA256 hash of verified data. `data` is the signature for verification.

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked ;) I'm almost sure I did something similar but with export/import parameters and then the result was false...

Comment: @kertoip It was not easy to find the right sequence :) In general the implementation of public key encryption in .Net is not very good. They have to implement raw encrypt/decrypt with public/private key instead of (or in addition to) methods like `Verify`/`Sign`.